# eBay API call GetSuggestedCategories via URL

Tags: url, uri, ebay-api

I can get categories from the eBay API using this:

> http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=YOUR-APP-ID&siteid=3&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories

Is there any way I can make a call to `GetSuggestedCategories` via a URL in this way?

I have tried various combinations but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck!

The `GetSuggestedCategories` call is part of the eBay [Trading API](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api), which doesn't have a REST endpoint (making API calls via a simple URL).

Unlike the Finding and Shopping APIs, to access the Trading API you need to send XML or SOAP requests using HTTPS POST.

The reason is, that the Trading API "offers secure, authenticated access to private eBay data."

It's a tool meant for Sellers, to be able to list items and manage their listings, so there's plenty of private data available through the Trading API - which is why you need a more secure method that a simple URL to access it.

Comment: Ah I thought as much, it does seem like they should move the call into the Finding Api though. Thanks for the info.